# VerifyError: Verifier rejected class models.AppModel

Tags: java, android, build, build.gradle, verifyerror

I am getting verify error on runtime:

> java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class models.AppModel: void models.AppModel.setToken(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.content.Context) failed to verify: void models.AppModel.setToken(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.content.Context): [0x8F] register v0 has type Undefined but expected Precise Reference: java.lang.String[] (declaration of 'models.AppModel' appears in base.apk)
> at models.AppModel.getInstance(AppModel.java:1)
> at managers.DatabaseManager.getAllUsers(DatabaseManager.java:3)

Here is my build.gradle(app):

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 24
        versionName "1.0.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
    }
    lintOptions{
        checkReleaseBuilds = false
        abortOnError = false
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('D:/project/ABC/abc.jks')
            storePassword 'abc123'
            keyPassword 'abc123'
            keyAlias = 'abc app'
        }


    }
    buildTypes {
        release {

            minifyEnabled true
            debuggable false
            //signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.8.4'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'
    implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.0.0'
//    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core'
    implementation 'com.scottyab:rootbeer-lib:0.0.9'
    debugImplementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.4'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

When i change debuggable to true in buildTypes release, app is not crashing and when i make it false to upload on google play it crashes on button click.